# jquery droppable area (not the object) not resizing with panzoom

Tags: jquery, zooming, droppable

I'm developing a puzzle for children.

I am using jquery panzoom for zooming and panning https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom

```
    $("#panzoom").panzoom(
    {
        $zoomIn: $("#zoomin").on("click"),
        $zoomOut: $("#zoomout").on("click"),
        maxScale: 1.2,
        minScale: largestSide/backgroundSize,
        increment: 0.05 
    });
    // Set start zoom
    $("#panzoom").panzoom("zoom",largestSide/backgroundSize);
```

and jquery draggable and droppable for .piece and .targetPuzzle, respectively

```
$(".targetPuzzle").droppable
({
    accept: '.piece',
    //tolerance: 'pointer',
    tolerance: 'touch',
    hoverClass: "highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui)
    {}
});
```

You can see my problem live here www.puzzstory.com/test-puzzle.html (turn display to none for #intro and #loading):

1. Take the piece and go towards the white area that is supposed to be my droppable div
2. When the white area turns yellow it means you are already hovering on top of the droppable area because in fact the area (not the div) is not resized by panzoom...??

Any idea on how to solve this?